# Captcha solution using omniauth-identity without devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, recaptcha

I am trying to insert a captcha in to my application's registration form. Most of the solutions ([ambethia/recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) and [achiu/rack-recaptcha](https://github.com/achiu/rack-recaptcha)) I have found are using a controller helper method to check whether the captcha is valid. That's great and all, but I'm using OmniAuth-identity for my simple authentication, which does not provide for a controller -- the user's registration form posts directly to the OmniAuth handler.

```
      = form_tag "/auth/identity/register", id: 'loginform' do 
        = error_messages_for @identity, :header_message => "" 

        %table
          %tr{colspan: 2} 
            %td
              = label_tag :title
              = text_field_tag :title, @identity.try(:title), size: '32'
          %tr
            %td
              = label_tag :first_name, nil, class: 'required'
              = text_field_tag :first_name, @identity.try(:first_name), size: '32'
            %td
              = label_tag :last_name, nil, class: 'required'
              = text_field_tag :last_name, @identity.try(:last_name), size: '32'
          %tr
            %td
              = label_tag :email, nil, class: 'required'
              = email_field_tag :email, @identity.try(:email), size: '32'
            %td
              = label_tag :phone, nil, class: 'required'
              = text_field_tag :phone, @identity.try(:phone), size: '32'
          %tr
            %td
              = label_tag :password, nil, class: 'required'
              = password_field_tag :password, nil, size: '32'
            %td
              = label_tag :password_confirmation, nil, class: 'required'
              = password_field_tag :password_confirmation, nil, size: '32'
          %tr
            %td{colspan: 2} 
              = label_tag 'recaptcha', "Captcha", class: 'required'
              = recaptcha_tags
          %tr
            %td{halign: 'right', colspan: 2} 
              = submit_tag 'Register', class: 'button'
```

I've tried everything from posting back to a custom controller which then tries to hit the register path, but that didn't work, model validation isn't possible with any of the gems I've seen (and violates MVC, anyways).

I'm not stuck on any of the reCAPTCHA solutions, I just need something which prevents automated registrations. I would just put devise back in here and be done with it, but my team has previously ripped it out and for some reason hate it. Is there some way to inject a controller between a form and omniauth-identity so that we can validate, or is there another gem which can do model validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I ended up with involved adding a custom hook to omniauth-identity, which allows you to specify a method to be called before verifying the login, etc, of the model. There's a [pull request](https://github.com/rebelhold/omniauth-identity/pull/1) on my organisation's clone which shows how to do this. It's inelegant and horrible, but it mostly works.